# Getting notifications from a BLE device in C# with GATT is not working

Tags: c#, .net, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm developing an application to receive data from an Arduino with a HM-10 module on it. I am writing a WPF .NET app, whilst using the UWP libraries for connecting to the BLE. I previously wrote a program to send data too and from the Arduino in a .NET Console application, which worked fine and I could send text to the Arduino and receive text back. When moving this over too my original project, it stopped working.

No error code was given, the program just stopped when attempting to subscribe to notifications from the characteristic that I was attempting to receive notifications from.

```
private static async void subscribeToData()
    {
        if (readwrite.CharacteristicProperties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting subscription");
            GattCommunicationStatus status = await readwrite.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                                    GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.None);
            if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recieving notifcations from device.");
                recieve = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(status);
            }
        }

    }
```

In the code above, the variable 'readwrite' is the characteristic that I am trying get notifications from. The console prints "Attempting subscription" then stops, with no error code. This code works fine in the console application, just not when copied across.

This is the full class:

```
class BluetoothHandler
    {
        private static BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher = new 
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher { ScanningMode = 
BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active };
        private static BluetoothLEDevice ble;
        private static List<GattCharacteristic> characterstics = new 
List<GattCharacteristic> { };
        private static GattCharacteristic readwrite;
        private static bool subscribe = true;
        private static bool recieve = true;

    public static void InitiateConnection()
    {
        GetDiscoverableDevices();
        while (subscribe)
        {
            //Block code
        }
        subscribeToData();
        while (recieve)
        {
            //Block code
        }
        readwrite.ValueChanged += recieveDataAsync;
    }

    private static async void subscribeToData()
    {
        if (readwrite.CharacteristicProperties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting subscription");
            GattCommunicationStatus status = await readwrite.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                                    GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.None);
            if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recieving notifcations from device.");
                recieve = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(status);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void recieveDataAsync(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(args.CharacteristicValue);
        //var stream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        uint bufferLength = (uint)reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;
        string receivedString = "";
        receivedString += reader.ReadString(bufferLength) + "\n";
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved Message: " + receivedString);
    }

    public static void GetDiscoverableDevices()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Search started");
        watcher.Received += bluetoothFoundAsync;
        watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;
        watcher.Start();
    }

    private static async void bluetoothFoundAsync(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        string deviceName = args.Advertisement.LocalName;
        if (deviceName == "Carduino")
        {
            var bdevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress);
            watcher.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Scan complete: Found Carduino");
            bdevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairingRequested +=
                    (ss, ev) =>
                    {
                        ev.Accept();
                    };
            var result = await bdevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly);
            Console.WriteLine($"Pairing Result: {result.Status}");
            if (result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.AlreadyPaired)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting Reconnection");
                var a = await bdevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing.UnpairAsync();
                var result2 = await bdevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly);
                Console.WriteLine($"Pairing Result: {result2.Status}");
            }
            ble = bdevice;
            getServices();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find device: 'Carduino'");
        }
    }

    private static async void getServices()
    {
        GattDeviceServicesResult result = await ble.GetGattServicesAsync();
        if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
        {
            var services = result.Services;
            getCharacterstics(services);
        }
    }

    private static async void getCharacterstics(IReadOnlyList<GattDeviceService> services)
    {
        foreach (GattDeviceService s in services)
        {
            GattCharacteristicsResult result = await s.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
            if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                var characteristicss = result.Characteristics;
                foreach (GattCharacteristic c in characteristicss)
                {
                    characterstics.Add(c);
                    if (c.Uuid == Guid.Parse("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
                    {
                        readwrite = c;
                        Console.WriteLine("Found read/write characteristic");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        subscribe = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Got characteristics");

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

After further testing, it only seems to work in a console .NET application, and not in a windows form app or a .NET WPF app.

Comment: Writing None to the descriptor turns off notifications... Didn't you want to turn them on? And please, don't use busy-loops since they eat CPU cycles (your while(variable) {/*block code*/}). There are many other better ways, for example Wait/Notify.

Comment: @Emil It works fine with the none in the other program. I had them on notify earlier and was just changing it to see if it worked. And yeah I'm sorry about the while loops, I did a quick google on a better way and didn't find much. How should I do it?

Comment: I will not post this as an answer, because it is UWP, not WPF.
Have a look at my example on GitHub:[link](https://github.com/GrooverFromHolland/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename)
And open MainPage.xaml.cs:[link](https://github.com/GrooverFromHolland/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename/blob/master/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename/MainPage.xaml.cs)
It will show you all you need to know to get you on your way.